# Solidity contract returns object rather than a string

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have this contract function

```
function getPrize(string memory data, bytes memory signature) public returns (string memory);
```

I use Mumbai test net if it makes any difference.

I send this function and expect it to return a string, but I get an object with hash and data and Gas fees that i sent. No error, transaction is successfully sent, but the answer is an object.

What could be wrong?

PS. i also have this function in contract

```
function verify(
string memory data,
bytes memory signature
) public view returns (bool)
```

It takes same arguments but returns Boolean, and it is working just fine.

Comment: how do you call it?

Comment: ``` const prizeResponse = await contract.getPrize(form.message, sig) ``` like this and then console.log response. That way i see that it returns an object

Answer (score 1):

Your function `getPrize` is not considered a view or pure function.

On the other hand, your `verify` function is a `view` function that works correctly and returns properly.

Here is the function corrected:

```
function getPrize(string memory data, bytes memory signature) public view returns (string memory);
```

Comment: I have no access to the contract, is there a way to modify my code in order to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Following the Adam's answer, if your function is intended to `read` some data from blockchain it should implement the `view access modifier`. But if you are doing some transaction stuff in that function like `changing or storing` some data in `state`, it will always return a object containing the transaction hash, gas fees, and other details, as you mentioned.
One thing to clear doubt about it is solidity compiler yields warning stating that you need to make your `getPrize()` function as view. but if your contract is compiling correctly without giving any warning that means you are actually modifying the state and in that case you'll always get the object as return.

Comment: the answer will always return the same? no matter if modifying was successful or not?

Comment: yes, even if the transaction was reverted you it will return a object, that'll contain the tx information like error message  "transaction reverted due to specific reasonsa"

Comment: and if a have an object with hash, gas fee, address and so on it means that transaction was successfully sent and modified a contract?